# Java crash within IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

When I launch intellij and select a maven project, Java crashes when the project is loaded/indexed. I get a popup saying: "Java Platform SE binary has stopped working".
I have tried with both the bundled java as well as using standalone version. I have also tried with using the bundled maven as well as a standalone version
I have reinstalled IntelliJ and also deleted the .IntelliJIdea2016.3 folder.
I'm using IntelliJ 2016.3.3.

Here are some entries from the intellij log:

```
2017-01-30 09:02:12,491 [      0]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
2017-01-30 09:02:12,507 [     16]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: IntelliJ IDEA (build #IU-163.11103.6, 16 Jan 2017 22:12) 
2017-01-30 09:02:12,522 [     31]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Windows 7 (6.1, x86) 
2017-01-30 09:02:12,522 [     31]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-408-b6 (JetBrains s.r.o) 
2017-01-30 09:02:12,522 [     31]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 25.112-b6 (OpenJDK Server VM) 
2017-01-30 09:02:12,522 [     31]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -ea -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Djb.vmOptionsFile=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\bin\idea.exe.vmoptions -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\lib\boot.jar -Didea.jre.check=true -Didea.paths.selector=IntelliJIdea2016.3 -XX:ErrorFile=C:\Users\A227645\java_error_in_idea_%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\Users\A227645\java_error_in_idea.hprof 
2017-01-30 09:02:12,522 [     31]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ext: C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\jre\jre\lib\ext: [access-bridge-32.jar, access-bridge.jar, cldrdata.jar, dnsns.jar, jaccess.jar, jfxrt.jar, localedata.jar, meta-index, nashorn.jar, sunec.jar, sunjce_provider.jar, sunmscapi.jar, sunpkcs11.jar, zipfs.jar] 
2017-01-30 09:02:12,522 [     31]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNU charset: Cp1252 
2017-01-30 09:02:12,569 [     78]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library (32-bit) loaded in 47 ms 
2017-01-30 09:02:12,585 [     94]   INFO - penapi.util.io.win32.IdeaWin32 - Native filesystem for Windows is operational 
2017-01-30 09:02:12,585 [     94]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - Using "FocusKiller" library to prevent focus stealing. 
2017-01-30 09:02:12,585 [     94]   INFO -     #com.intellij.util.ui.JBUI - UI scale factor: 1.0 
2017-01-30 09:02:13,661 [   1170]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor plugin-intelliLang.xml 
2017-01-30 09:02:14,193 [   1702]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - 128 plugins initialized in 1015 ms 
2017-01-30 09:02:14,208 [   1717]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded bundled plugins: ASP (0.1), Android Support (10.2.2), Ant Support (1.0), Application Servers View (0.2.0), AspectJ Support (1.2), Bytecode Viewer (0.1), CFML Support (3.53), CSS Support (163.11103.6), CVS Integration (11), ClearCase Integration (2.0), Cloud Foundry integration (1.0), CloudBees integration (1.0), CoffeeScript (2.0), Copyright (8.1), Coverage (163.11103.6), Cucumber for Groovy (999.999), Cucumber for Java (999.999), DSM Analysis (1.0.0), Database Tools and SQL (1.0), Eclipse Integration (3.0), EditorConfig (163.11103.6), Emma (163.11103.6), Flash/Flex Support (163.11103.6), FreeMarker support (1.0), GWT Support (1.0), Geronimo Integration (1.0), Gherkin (999.999), Git Integration (8.1), GitHub (163.11103.6), GlassFish Integration (1.0), Google App Engine Integration (1.1.4), Gradle (163.11103.6), Grails (9.0), Groovy (9.0), Guice (8.0), HAML (163.11103.6), HTML Tools (2.0), Heroku integration (1.0), Hibernate Support (1.0), I18n for Java (163.11103.6), IDEA CORE (163.11103.6), IntelliLang (8.0), J2ME (1.0), JBA Cloud Config (163.11103.6), JBoss Arquillian Support (1.0), JBoss Drools Support (1.0), JBoss Integration (1.0), JBoss Seam Pageflow Support (1.0), JBoss Seam Pages Support (1.0), JBoss Seam Support (1.0), JBoss Support (1.0), JBoss jBPM (2.0.0), JSR45 Integration (1.0), JUnit (1.0), Java Bytecode Decompiler (163.11103.6), Java EE: Batch Applications (1.0), Java EE: Bean Validation Support (1.1), Java EE: Contexts and Dependency Injection (1.1), Java EE: EJB, JPA, Servlets (1.0), Java EE: JMS, JSON Processing, Concurrency, Transaction  (1.0), Java EE: Java Server Faces (2.2.X.), Java EE: RESTful Web Services (JAX-RS) (1.0), Java EE: Web Services (JAX-WS) (1.9), Java EE: WebSockets (1.0), Java Server Pages (JSP) Integration (1.0), JavaFX (1.0), JavaScript Debugger (1.0), JavaScript Intention Power Pack (0.9.4), JavaScript Support (1.0), Jetty Integration (1.0), Kotlin (1.0.5-release-IJ2016.3-1), LESS support (163.11103.6), Markdown support (VERSION), Maven Integration (163.11103.6), Maven Integration Extension (163.11103.6), OpenShift integration (1.0), Osmorc (1.4.9), Perforce Integration (2.0), Persistence Frameworks Support (1.0), Playframework Support (1.0), Plugin DevKit (1.0), Properties Support (163.11103.6), QuirksMode (163.11103.6), REST Client (163.11103.6), Refactor-X (2.01), Remote Hosts Access (0.1), Resin Integration (8.1), SASS support (163.11103.6), SSH Remote Run (0.1), Settings Repository (163.11103.6), Spring AOP/@AspectJ (1.0), Spring Batch (1.0), Spring Boot (1.0), Spring Data (1.0), Spring Integration Patterns (1.0), Spring MVC (1.0), Spring OSGi (1.0), Spring Security (1.0), Spring Support (1.0), Spring Web Flow (1.0), Spring Web Services (1.0), Spring WebSocket (1.0), Spy-js (163.11103.6), Struts 1.x (2.0), Struts 2 (1.0), Stylus support (999.999), Subversion Integration (1.1), TFS Integration (999.999), Tapestry support (1.0), Task Management (1.0), Terminal (0.1), TestNG-J (8.0), Thymeleaf (1.0), Time Tracking (1.0), Tomcat and TomEE Integration (1.0), UI Designer (163.11103.6), UML Support (1.0), Vaadin Support (1.0), Velocity support (1.0), W3C Validators (2.0), WebLogic Integration (1.0), WebSphere Integration (1.0), XPathView + XSLT Support (4), XSLT-Debugger (1.4), YAML (163.11103.6), ZKM-Unscramble (1.0), dmServer Support (0.9.5), hg4idea (10.0) 
2017-01-30 09:02:16,330 [   3839]   INFO - ellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage - lower=100; upper=200; buffer=10; max=474 
2017-01-30 09:02:16,391 [   3900]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Starting file watcher: C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\bin\fsnotifier.exe 
2017-01-30 09:02:16,406 [   3915]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Native file watcher is operational. 
2017-01-30 09:02:17,343 [   4852]   INFO - rains.ide.BuiltInServerManager - built-in server started, port 63342 
2017-01-30 09:02:17,345 [   4854]   INFO - gs.impl.UpdateCheckerComponent - channel: release 
2017-01-30 09:02:17,510 [   5019]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - Index exts enumerated:98 
2017-01-30 09:02:17,510 [   5019]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - Index scheduled:4 
2017-01-30 09:02:17,514 [   5023]   INFO - tellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl - All stub exts enumerated:22 
2017-01-30 09:02:17,514 [   5023]   INFO - tellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl - stub exts update scheduled:0 
2017-01-30 09:02:17,607 [   5116]   INFO - j.ide.script.IdeStartupScripts - 0 startup script(s) found 
2017-01-30 09:02:18,061 [   5570]   INFO - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - 98 application components initialized in 4899ms 
2017-01-30 09:02:18,092 [   5601]   INFO - .intellij.idea.IdeaApplication - App initialization took 7134 ms 
2017-01-30 09:02:18,650 [   6159]   INFO - pl$FileIndexDataInitialization - Initialization done:1140 
2017-01-30 09:02:18,994 [   6503]   INFO - exImpl$StubIndexInitialization - Initialization done:342 
2017-01-30 09:02:19,350 [   6859]   INFO - CompilerWorkspaceConfiguration - Available processors: 8 
2017-01-30 09:02:20,040 [   7549]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - Finished preloading com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionPreloader@286303 
2017-01-30 09:02:20,337 [   7846]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 185 project components initialized in 1725 ms 
2017-01-30 09:02:20,649 [   8158]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 1 module(s) loaded in 312 ms 
2017-01-30 09:02:21,632 [   9141]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 32ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2017-01-30 09:02:21,634 [   9143]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - Finished preloading com.intellij.ide.ui.search.SearchableOptionPreloader@236e57 
2017-01-30 09:02:22,153 [   9662]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - Finished preloading com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionPreloader@82e48c 
2017-01-30 09:02:23,353 [  10862]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 1721ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: 1/2 sluggish 
2017-01-30 09:02:23,821 [  11330]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - C:/Users/A227645/src/opus/provisioning-mailer/.idea case-sensitivity: expected=false actual=false 
2017-01-30 09:02:24,195 [  11704]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java" -Djava.awt.headless=true -Didea.version==2016.3.3 -Xmx768m -Didea.maven.embedder.version=3.3.9 -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath "C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3/lib/resources_en.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\lib\log4j.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\lib\jna.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\lib\snappy-in-java-0.5.1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\lib\resources_en.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\lib\oromatcher.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\lib\jna-platform.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\lib\trove4j.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\lib\util.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\lib\annotations.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\lib\jdom.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\plugins\maven\lib\lucene-core-2.4.1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven-server-api.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3-server-common.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3-server-lib\archetype-catalog-2.2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3-server-lib\archetype-common-2.2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3-server-lib\maven-dependency-tree-1.2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3-server-lib\nexus-indexer-3.0.4.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3-server-lib\nexus-indexer-artifact-1.0.1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3-server-impl.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\aether-api-1.0.2.v20150114.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\aether-connector-basic-1.0.2.v20150114.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\aether-impl-1.0.2.v20150114.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\aether-spi-1.0.2.v20150114.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\aether-transport-wagon-1.0.2.v20150114.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\aether-util-1.0.2.v20150114.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\aopalliance-1.0.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\cdi-api-1.0.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\commons-cli-1.2.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\commons-io-2.2.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\commons-lang-2.6.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\commons-lang3-3.4.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\guava-18.0.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\guice-4.0-no_aop.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\javax.inject-1.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\jsoup-1.7.2.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\jsr250-api-1.0.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\maven-aether-provider-3.3.9.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\maven-artifact-3.3.9.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\maven-builder-support-3.3.9.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\maven-compat-3.3.9.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\maven-core-3.3.9.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\maven-embedder-3.3.9.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\maven-model-3.3.9.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\maven-model-builder-3.3.9.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\maven-plugin-api-3.3.9.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\maven-repository-metadata-3.3.9.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\maven-settings-3.3.9.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\maven-settings-builder-3.3.9.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.3.2.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\org.eclipse.sisu.plexus-0.3.2.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\plexus-cipher-1.7.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\plexus-component-annotations-1.6.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\plexus-interpolation-1.21.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\plexus-utils-3.0.22.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\wagon-file-2.10.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\wagon-http-2.10-shaded.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\wagon-http-shared-2.10.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\wagon-provider-api-2.10.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar" org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteMavenServer 
2017-01-30 09:02:24,852 [  12361]   INFO - tor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl - Project opening took 6391 ms 
2017-01-30 09:03:29,380 [  76889]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java" -Djava.awt.headless=true -Didea.version==2016.3.3 -Xmx768m -Didea.maven.embedder.version=3.3.9 -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath "C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3/lib/resources_en.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\lib\log4j.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\lib\jna.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\lib\snappy-in-java-0.5.1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\lib\resources_en.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\lib\oromatcher.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\lib\jna-platform.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\lib\trove4j.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\lib\util.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\lib\annotations.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\lib\jdom.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\plugins\maven\lib\lucene-core-2.4.1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven-server-api.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3-server-common.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3-server-lib\archetype-catalog-2.2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3-server-lib\archetype-common-2.2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3-server-lib\maven-dependency-tree-1.2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3-server-lib\nexus-indexer-3.0.4.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3-server-lib\nexus-indexer-artifact-1.0.1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3-server-impl.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\aether-api-1.0.2.v20150114.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\aether-connector-basic-1.0.2.v20150114.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\aether-impl-1.0.2.v20150114.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\aether-spi-1.0.2.v20150114.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\aether-transport-wagon-1.0.2.v20150114.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\aether-util-1.0.2.v20150114.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\aopalliance-1.0.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\cdi-api-1.0.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\commons-cli-1.2.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\commons-io-2.2.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\commons-lang-2.6.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\commons-lang3-3.4.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\guava-18.0.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\guice-4.0-no_aop.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\javax.inject-1.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\jsoup-1.7.2.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\jsr250-api-1.0.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\maven-aether-provider-3.3.9.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\maven-artifact-3.3.9.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\maven-builder-support-3.3.9.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\maven-compat-3.3.9.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\maven-core-3.3.9.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\maven-embedder-3.3.9.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\maven-model-3.3.9.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\maven-model-builder-3.3.9.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\maven-plugin-api-3.3.9.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\maven-repository-metadata-3.3.9.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\maven-settings-3.3.9.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\maven-settings-builder-3.3.9.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.3.2.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\org.eclipse.sisu.plexus-0.3.2.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\plexus-cipher-1.7.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\plexus-component-annotations-1.6.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\plexus-interpolation-1.21.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\plexus-utils-3.0.22.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\wagon-file-2.10.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\wagon-http-2.10-shaded.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\wagon-http-shared-2.10.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\lib\wagon-provider-api-2.10.jar;C:\Users\A227645\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar" org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteMavenServer 
2017-01-30 09:03:29,942 [  77451]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Cannot reconnect. 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot reconnect.
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.perform(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:82)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.applyProfiles(MavenServerManager.java:555)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader.applyProfiles(MavenProjectReader.java:397)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader.doReadProjectModel(MavenProjectReader.java:103)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader.access$300(MavenProjectReader.java:46)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader$1.doProcessParent(MavenProjectReader.java:450)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader$1.doProcessParent(MavenProjectReader.java:427)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenParentProjectFileProcessor.processRepositoryParent(MavenParentProjectFileProcessor.java:84)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenParentProjectFileProcessor.process(MavenParentProjectFileProcessor.java:62)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader.resolveInheritance(MavenProjectReader.java:453)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader.doReadProjectModel(MavenProjectReader.java:100)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader.readProject(MavenProjectReader.java:62)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProject.read(MavenProject.java:631)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsTree.doUpdate(MavenProjectsTree.java:560)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsTree.doAdd(MavenProjectsTree.java:505)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsTree.update(MavenProjectsTree.java:466)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsTree.updateAll(MavenProjectsTree.java:437)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessorReadingTask.perform(MavenProjectsProcessorReadingTask.java:60)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessor.doProcessPendingTasks(MavenProjectsProcessor.java:130)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessor.access$000(MavenProjectsProcessor.java:30)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessor$2.run(MavenProjectsProcessor.java:105)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.utils.MavenUtil.lambda$runInBackground$5(MavenUtil.java:458)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.rmi.RemoteException: Cannot start maven service; nested exception is: 
    com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: 
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.create(MavenServerManager.java:173)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.create(MavenServerManager.java:78)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.getOrCreateWrappee(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:41)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager$7.execute(MavenServerManager.java:558)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager$7.execute(MavenServerManager.java:555)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.perform(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:76)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: 
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport.acquire(RemoteProcessSupport.java:159)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.create(MavenServerManager.java:170)
    ... 32 more
```

I tried to solve it by following the steps mentioned here: [Intellij - Cannot start maven service - ExecutionException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754344/intellij-cannot-start-maven-service-executionexception).
Unfortunately this didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Tried with launching IntelliJ with another JVM than the one bundled?  You may want to raise an issue with JetBrains.  https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66731

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Yes, I have tried that as well. I have already raised an issue with JetBrains

Comment: I would suspect that you have a bad configuration.  If you do this as a newly created user from scratch on your own machine do you see  the problem?  Do you see the problem on another machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to downgrade the graphics driver. See this link for information: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000077464-Java-crashes-with-maven